# Is there any way to recover the KeyStore file?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have lost my KeyStore file andI didn't enable Google Play SignIn. Is there any way to recover the KeyStore file?

Answer (score 1):

Use this step and recover the keystore file

```
(1) Mail Play Console Help below is link:

 https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423? 
 hl=en#contact=1

(2) To request the reset of your upload keystore if you lost it

(3) After Request google say make new KEYSTORE  

(4) After genrate  new KEYSTORE  you have make PEM Certificate Send to google
 (Make Sure Only send PEM Certificate send to google not JKS file)

(5) Now You make PEM Certificate From  From JKS

(6) You can make PEM certificate through cmd

 keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore 
 keystore.jks
```

Example of generate PEM certificate

```
 keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file 
/Users/shiv/Desktop/App_Key_Store/upload_certificate.pem -keystore 
 /Users/shiv/Desktop/App_Key_Store/App_New.jks
```

This process may tack time to 3-4 day to recover you keysotre